# WordPress Hosted on Apache Served With Nginx - Reverse Proxy not working for certain folders

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress

So I have the blog on `blog.gokyma.com` hosted on Apached.

The goal is to reverse proxy the blog to `gokyma.com/blog/`. 
gokyma.com is on Ngninx. 
I have set up like that on Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name .gokyma.com;

    location /blog {
        proxy_pass https://blog.gokyma.com/;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Is-Reverse-Proxy "true";
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_cookie_path / /blog/;
        expires off;
    }
[...]
```

In the wordpress config file I have:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
define('WP_HOME','https://gokyma.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://gokyma.com/blog');
```

Now when you open gokyma.com/blog you get the right page BUT the wp-content wp-includes & wp-admin won't work at all.

I have no clue why...

Any idea? 
Thanks for looking into it, I've been struggling for a while now.... :/

Comment: Why are you using both Apache and Nginx? Either are capable of doing both jobs. Can you edit your question to expand on why you're doing things this way, though it probably won't help you get a better answer.

Comment: Hey Tim. Simply because it's not hosted on the same server and I can move the blog to Nginx. but I don't think knowing why doesn't really matter? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are using `proxy_pass` to remove the leading `/blog` from the URI before passing it upstream. The lack of a trailing `/` in the `location` directive means that the aliasing will not work correctly. Try using a `rewrite ... break` instead:

```
location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://blog.gokyma.com;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks so much for looking into it - driving me crazy... 
I just tried and it won't change anything. :/